Writing a single partial derivative as a Jacobian
I was looking here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_relations#Derivation_based_on_Jacobians
And am confused at:

If I follow the definition of a Jacobian,
$\frac{\partial (T,S)}{\partial (V,S)} =
\begin{vmatrix}
(\frac{\partial T}{\partial{V}})_S & (\frac{\partial T}{\partial{S}})_V\\
(\frac{\partial S}{\partial{V}})_T & (\frac{\partial S}{\partial{S}})_{V,T} \end{vmatrix}
= (\frac{\partial T}{\partial{V}})_S \times 1 - (\frac{\partial T}{\partial{S}})_V (\frac{\partial S}{\partial{V}})_T \\
=(\frac{\partial T}{\partial{V}})_S - (-(\frac{\partial T}{\partial{V}})_S)
=2 (\frac{\partial T}{\partial{V}})_S$
where the second to last equality has come from the reciprocal rule:
$(\frac{\partial T}{\partial{S}})_V (\frac{\partial S}{\partial{V}})_T (\frac{\partial V}{\partial{T}})_S = -1$
hence $(\frac{\partial T}{\partial{S}})_V (\frac{\partial S}{\partial{V}})_T = -(\frac{\partial T}{\partial{V}})_S$

So I get 2x what wikipedia does. What am I doing wrong?

Don't use images for Math. Instead, type the relevant passage (too).
